# How to match Form Type with Request?

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

Request JSON:

```
{"vpnusers": {"expire_account": "2017-11-27 16:28:15", "status_id": 1}}
```

The result printed (in the controller):

```
print_r($request->get('vpnusers'));
Array
(
    [expire_account] => 2017-11-27 16:28:15
    [status_id] => 1
)
```

VpnUsersType:

```
namespace Hoax\PartnerBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class VpnUsersType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('status_id')
            ->add('expire_account')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Hoax\PartnerBundle\Entity\VpnUsers'
            , 'csrf_protection' => false
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'vpnusers';
    }
}
```

I have just followed this guide and can see there's no such issue as I have: http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set `data_class` option `Hoax\PartnerBundle\Entity\VpnUsers' since what you are submitting is not an object.

Either set that to `NULL` or create an object from request data and pass it to you form.

In case of `NULL` you are very close:

1. set `data_class` to null
2. In controller do the following:

   ```
   $form = $this->createForm(new VpnUsersType(), $request->get('vpnusers'));
   ```

In case you go for object type:

1. leave `data_class` be
2. In controller:

   ```
   $req_data = $request->get('vpnusers');

   // either fetch from database **or** creare new instance here, your call...
   $vpnUser = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('HoaxPartnerBundle:VpnUsers')->find($req_data['status_id']); // IS THIS OK? Not sure really...
   $form = $this->createForm(new VpnUsersType(), $vpnUser);
   ```

Comment: Right, probably the second approach is more reasonable as I can lookup for an item... I have just followed this guide and can see there's no such issue as I have: http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/

Comment: What is the difference between my code and William DURAND's one? In his case, data is mapped correctly.

Comment: Show us where you map $request->get('vpnusers') to your VpnUser entity.  I'm guessing your entity uses statusId and expiresAccounnt.

Comment: Thanks! I have fixed it by using second approach - `findOneBy()` added.